See docker name of services in petitions inside the same docker network
so I have multiple services runing in the same docker network with flask
they are set like this:
version: '3'
services:
  login:
    build:
      context: ./repo_login
      dockerfile: Development.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./repo_login:/home/app
    ports:
      - "5007:5001"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ENV: 'development'
    networks:
      - qa_network
  jobs:
    build:
      context: ./repo_jobs
      dockerfile: Development.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./repo_jobs:/home/app
    ports:
      - "5017:5001"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
      ENV: 'development'
    networks:
      - qa_network
  sla:
    build:
      context: ./repo_sla
      dockerfile: Development.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./repo_sla:/home/app
    ports:
      - "5008:5001"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ENV: 'development'
    networks:
      - qa_network

I know I can petitions from on service to the another using only the service name like this:
requests.post('http://jobs:5001/some/api', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
but is there a way to know from which service a petition came from?
I already try with request.environ, but I only get An IP and port from whitch I don't know its service. I used the next code
@app.route('/some/api', methods=['POST'])
def execute_task():
    try:
        origin = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
        origin_port = request.environ['REMOTE_PORT']
        logging.warning(f'the origin of the petition is: {origin} : {origin_port}')
   except Exception as ex:
        data = None
        message = getattr(ex, 'message', str(ex))
        logging.exception(ex)


Why do you want to know?  Unless you have something like a mutual-TLS setup, this is something that's hard to find out in any context; Docker doesn't make it particularly easier or harder.

I need to know where a petition comes from becuse there is a notification process in jobs that changes based on that information

I found a way
you can resolve de dns for the services that you have and compare it with the remote_addr in the request
Something like this:
@app.route('/some/api', methods=['POST'])
def execute_task():
    try:
        payload = request.json
        origin = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
        val = '172.18.0.0'
        result = dns.resolver.resolve('login', 'A')
        if len(result) >= 1:
            val = result[0].to_text()
        if val == origin:
            logging.warning(f'The origin of the petition is login)
        else:
            logging.warning(f'The origin of the petition is not login')
    except Exception as ex:
        data = None
        message = getattr(ex, 'message', str(ex))
        logging.exception(ex)

This can be expanded to check all the services you have

you can use more advanced tools like service discovery systems that do the job. But there is a simple solution for it if you don't want to use those tools.
You can add the headers in your requester application, like:
import requests
headers = {'service': 'foo'}
requests.post('http://jobs:5001/some/api', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

and then in your receiver application, you can check the headers:
from flask import request
serviceName = request.headers.get('service')

Then you will have the service name to play with.
